# Problems with apply android plugin

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, gradle

I am trying to set up gradle in ubuntu, but I am getting an error:

```
line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':GradleApplication'.
Cause: org/gradle/internal/reflect/Instantiator
Cause: org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator
```

line 10 in my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

my `etc/environment` file is

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
    $GRADLE_HOME/bin:~/android-sdk-linux/tools:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
GRADLE_HOME="/android_projects/gradle-1.8"
```

> ```
> env:
> ```

```
ANDROID_HOME=/root/android-sdks-linux
GRADLE_HOME=/android_projects/gradle-1.8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/android_projects/gradle-1.8/bin:~/android-sdk-linux/tools:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Please, help me fix this.

Comment: Hi, have you fixed this problem? I am having the same problem now and don't know how to do with it.

Comment: yes, try to check root permissions or the problems can be in different environment conf files

Answer (score 1):

In my case a `sudo` helped. Seems like this Installation needs admin permissions.

> sudo gradle build